# Magento Java SOAP Client

Tags: java, magento, soap, cxf

i started developing a java client by using apache cxf. i tried to login and create a call to get a list of stores of my magenta installation. this worked find. but then i tried to receive a list of all products of the webshop. now i get a interesting error-message!

i am using Magento 1.6.1.0 and it runs in ws-i mode!

```
    URL wsdlURL = new URL("http://someurl/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1");

    MagentoService ss = new MagentoService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
    MageApiModelServerWsiHandlerPortType port = ss.getMageApiModelServerWsiHandlerPort();

    LoginParam loginParam = new LoginParam();
    loginParam.setApiKey("password");
    loginParam.setUsername("user");

    LoginResponseParam sessionId = port.login(loginParam);
    System.out.println("sessionId : " + sessionId.getResult());

    StoreListRequestParam param = new StoreListRequestParam();
    param.setSessionId(sessionId.getResult());
    StoreListResponseParam storeListRespParam = port.storeList(param);
    StoreEntityArray storeEntityArray = storeListRespParam.getResult();
    List<StoreEntity> stores = storeEntityArray.getComplexObjectArray();
    System.out.println(">>>> " + stores.size());

    StoreEntity store = stores.get(0);

    CatalogProductListRequestParam params = new CatalogProductListRequestParam();
    params.setSessionId(sessionId.getResult());
    params.setFilters(null);
    params.setStore(String.valueOf(store.getStoreId()));

    CatalogProductListResponseParam response = port.catalogProductList(params);
    CatalogProductEntityArray catalogProdEntityArray = response.getResult();
    List<CatalogProductEntity> products = catalogProdEntityArray.getComplexObjectArray();
    System.out.println(">>>> " + products.size());
```

The error message:

**[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element**

it seems that there is something wrong with the structure of the response!?

has someone an idea!?

thanks in advance

the whole stack trace:

```
 Interceptor for {urn:Magento}MagentoService#{urn:Magento}catalogProductList has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <sku>
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [3336,6] 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:824)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:644)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:156)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:801)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1627)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1494)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1402)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:649)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:535)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:465)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:368)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:321)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    at $Proxy24.catalogProductList(Unknown Source)
    at Client.main(Client.java:53)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <sku>
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [3336,6]]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:426)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:362)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:339)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:784)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$100(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$1.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:812)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:810)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <sku>
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [3336,6]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:677)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.throwUnexpectedEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:5466)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2685)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:192)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:360)
    ... 26 more
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <sku>
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [3336,6] 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:156)
    at $Proxy24.catalogProductList(Unknown Source)
    at Client.main(Client.java:53)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <sku>
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [3336,6]]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:426)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:362)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:339)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:784)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$100(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$1.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:812)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:810)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:644)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:156)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:801)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1627)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1494)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1402)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:649)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:535)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:465)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:368)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:321)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <sku>
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [3336,6]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:677)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.throwUnexpectedEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:5466)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2685)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:192)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:360)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: use the soap testing tool called soapui for inspecting the soap response. www.soapui.com

Comment: this issue could also be solved by turning of chunking messages in apache cxf: 

HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();        httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);

Comment: I know you solved it, but I've noticed the issue as well and it seems to occur when retrieving large result sets or when the Magento server itself is busy as well.  I assume that turning off chunking forces Magento to wait until the entire response is built before sending it, but would be interested in an elaboration